# Uncertainty in the output when 10 is raised to the power of a value with an associated uncertainty?

Tags: error-propagation

For the purpose of error propagation, I need to raise 10 to the power of a value with an uncertainty. How would this error be propagated to the new 'out' value?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the value $x$ is in the range $\alpha < x < \beta,$ then $10^x$ is in the range $10^\alpha < 10^x < 10^\beta.$ Was there something more to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Section 3.7 of *An Introduction to Error Analysis: the Study of Uncertainties in Physical Measurements, Second Edition* by John R. Taylor,

> If $x$ is measured with uncertainty $\delta x$ and is used to calculate
>   the function $q(x)$, then the uncertainty $\delta q$ is 
>   $$\delta q = \left| \frac{dq}{dx} \right| \delta x$$

If $q(x) = 10^x$, then $q'(x) = \ln(10)\cdot 10^x$, so $\delta q = \ln(10) \cdot 10^x \delta x$.

Comment: That's good for small values of the uncertainty.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Correct, that's the context of "error analysis": we have some relatively small uncertainties in our input or inputs, and we want to know what effect they have on the final result of some computation.

Comment: You know that, and I know that, but does Ralphie know that? For that matter, where is Ralphie? Hasn't had any engagement with your answer, hasn't accepted it – are you still here, Ralphie?